# jpype dbapi2 : ClassNotFoundException error on python

Tags: python, ibm-midrange, jpype

I want to run SQL on an IBM i database from **python**, with jpype and jdbc. The problem I have must be from jpype, all seems correct (the informations that  I print from my program), but I have a "ClassNotFoundException'.
I downloaded and installed in my folder IBM's jar (jt400-20.0.6.jar) Then I ran this simple test

```
import os
import jpype
import jpype.dbapi2

driver_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "jt400-20.0.6.jar")

jpype.startJVM()
print('startJVM effectué')

jpype.addClassPath(driver_file_path)
class_path = jpype.getClassPath(True)
print("Class Path " + class_path)

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")

connection_string = 'jdbc:as400://MACHINE'

try:
    cnx = jpype.dbapi2.connect(connection_string, driver= "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver",
                     driver_args={
                            "user": 'UTIL',
                            "password": 'MOTPASSE',
                            "extended metadata": "true",
                        }
                    )
except jpype.dbapi2.Error as err:
    print("Erreur" + err)
```

The driver exists at the driver_file_path that is printed. There's an AS400JDBCDriver.class in com\ibm\as400\access in the jar file (I opened the file with 7 zip to see it) When running, I have this informations

```
startJVM effectué
Class Path C:\Users...\jt400-20.0.6.jar
hello world
```

So the path should have been added to the jvm, and java is working... But I have also

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Test_jpype_question.py", line 37, in <module>
    cnx = jpype.dbapi2.connect(connection_string, driver= "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver",
  File "C:\...\jpype\dbapi2.py", line 404, in connect
    _jpype.JClass('java.lang.Class').forName(driver).newInstance()
java.lang.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

I tried lot of things, but I can't understand what's wrong. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Did you try to add the classpath before the jvm is started ? [Docs](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#class-paths) say "Calls to set the class path after the JVM is started are silently ignored"

Comment: Yes, you're right!
But now, if I add the path before the startJVM, then the program stops working immediatly, without any error or information. 
I give up. Jpype is just not working (I didn't understand it was still in alpha stage)